# Render mathjax as php variable

Tags: php, html, mathjax

I have mathjax rendering problem, Mathjax shown perfectly in html but when I put it as php variable it doesnt work well.

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="beeadmin/MathJax/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
   <script>
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
</script>
<!-- script untuk refresh/reload mathjax setiap content baru !-->

This is HTML<br>    
Will Share \(\frac{4}{5}\) to others
<br><br>

<?php
$var1 = "<br>This is PHP<br>
Will Share \(\frac{4}{5}\) to others.";

?>
<?= $var1 ?>
```

Thats my code, well I want to have second render as well as the first (html) one. Kindly note I also want the formula shown inline. Thanks

Comment: Try escaping the backslashes? I don't know PHP but that looks suspicious...

Comment: Then update your code./ What exactly is "doesn't work well? What HTML you get?

Comment: ([edit] your question with the escaped code)

Comment: Awesome youre right buddy, I tried adding backslash before the backslahes. Its pretty cool. Thank Youso much

Comment: what was your solution for this? I did not understand how you can add mathjax in php variable

Comment: its not add mathjax in php variable, its latex in php variable rendered by mathjax. cmiiw as Im PHP beginer